# Why is my Kantu script slow?

Tags: json, imacros

using Kantu (2.5.0) for chrome (64.0.3282.18) (windows)

I have a simple script that pushes a button.  It's supposed to do it about once every 2 seconds.

```html
{
  "CreationDate": "2018-2-24",
  "Commands": [
    {
      "Command": "click",
      "Target": "id=btnSearchTrade",
      "Value": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I want it to loop unlimited but I don't see how to do that so I just push the "play loop" button and type in 999999999.   It starts out pushing the button about once every 2 seconds but as time goes on it gets progressively slower.

After about an hour it can only manage to push the button once every 10 seconds.

The only way to get it back up to speed is to restart chrome entirely.

I've tried pushing the "clear" button to clear the log file, I've tried stopping and starting the macro again but that doesn't change the speed.

Is there something I can do to make this macro not be so slow?